# How to display default value on VF Page load in Picklist

Tags: visualforce

I hv a vf page where i need to populate default value as ' United States' on [page load and also geography field should get all the regions related to United States.

Below is my controller method.

Controller -

```
public List<SelectOption> getDept()
    {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult departfield =  Geography__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklist = departfield.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){      
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));

        }    
        return options;

     }
```

Regards

Comment: so 1) what isn't working? and 2) can you reduce the size of the code to only the relevant bits

Comment: Hi Crop.. I hv done it..

Answer (score 1):

The getter/setter for the selected value needs to be initialized to the default value in your controller.  I believe this has been answered here [Visualforce-selectlist-with-default-controller-setup](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/visualforce-selectlist-with-default-controller-setup)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [isDefaultValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm#apex_Schema_PicklistEntry_isDefaultValue).

```
public String defaultValue { get; set; }

public List<SelectOption> getDept()
{
    // get your picklist entries
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){
        // perform existing logic
        if (f.isDefaultValue()) defaultValue = f.getValue();
    }
}
```